# Qual o ditado correto: "Eu tardo, mas não falho" ou "Eu tardo, mas não ardo"

Tags: significado-em-contexto, ditados

Minha pergunta seria sobre se existe o ditado "Eu tardo, mas não ardo" e qual seria o significado dele. Me lembro de ter aprendido este ditado na escola nas primeiras séries, e sempre o utilizei no sentido de apesar de chegar tarde sempre chegava; ou de demorar para fazer algo porém ser exitoso no final.

Porém ouço também este outro ditado: "Eu tardo, mas não falho". Logo minha dúvida é: Existem estes dois ditados? Qual seria o significado de "Eu tardo, mas não ardo". Gostaria de respostas com alguma referência.

Comment: Que interessante, acho que nunca tinha ouvido «arder» com esse sentido... :) Estou curioso para ver as respostas que apareçam.

Comment: Tbm nunca ouvi: tardo, mas não ardo. Acredito que possa ser um trocadilho ou uma derivação do ditado original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Tardo mas não falho” existe e quer dizer que eu demoro mas acabo por chegar ou por fazer o que disse que faria. “Tardo mas não ardo” existe pelo menos no teu meio, mas parece ser muito raro em geral: encontrei no Google Search  uma única ocorrência independente da tua pergunta.

Andei a vasculhar a [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://bndigital.bn.gov.br/hemeroteca-digital/), que reúne o texto integral de centenas de periódicos brasileiros ao longo dos últimos dois séculos, e tudo isso parece vir do provérbio, “**Deus tarda mas não falta**”, que já vem do século XIX. Mais tarde é que aparece “**Deus tarda mas não falha**”. Só mais recentemente é que encontro, e muito raramente, “**eu tardo mas não falho**”; mas é frequente no Google Search. O provérbio original praticamente nem precisa de explicação. Na cultura cristã acredita-se que, se Deus permite por enquanto grassar a injustiça no mundo, a justiça divina há de por fim prevalecer. A versão pessoal “eu tardo mas não falho” é mera analogia.

“**Deus tarda mas não falta**” aparece pela primeira vez na Hemeroteca em 1831 [(*O Universal*, 16-2-1831)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=706930&pesq=deus%20tarda&pasta=ano%20183), e em 1845 é descrito como “provérbio” (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Possam exemplos taes fazer arripiar na carreira do crime tantas auctoridades, que parecem ter em nada os direitos e as garantias individuaes. Estremeçam ellas contemplando sua obra ; tarde ou cedo, o remedio apparecerá; **reflictam no proverbio—Deus tarda, mas não falta.—**
> [“Noticias Proviciaes”, *Sentinella da Monarchia*, Rio de Janeiro, 11 de agosto de 1845, p. 3.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=332780&pesq=deus%20tarda&pasta=ano%20184)

Aparece com muita frequência a partir de 1860, mas dado que a imprensa brasileira cresceu imenso ao longo do século, isso não quer dizer que o provérbio fosse antes menos popular.

“**Deus tarda mas não falha**” aparece pela primeira na Hemeroteca em 1862 [(*Jornal do Commercio*, RJ, 30-1-1862)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_05&pesq=tarda%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20falha&pasta=ano%20186). Entretanto, começa a ver-se “a justiça de Deus tarda mas não falha” [(*Correio Paulistano*, 20-12-1873)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=090972_03&pesq=tarda%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20falha&pasta=ano%20187). Em 1882 temos , simplesmente “a justiça tarda mas não falha” [(*Constituição*, 19-2-1882)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=235334&pesq=tarda%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20falha&pasta=ano%20188), que em 1885 é descrito como “adágio”:

> Tudo é inutil porém : — a justiça tarda, mas não falha, diz o adagio popular
> [“Chronica”, *O Cearense*, Fortaleza, 12 de março de 1885, p. 2.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=709506&pesq=tarda%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20falha&pasta=ano%20188)

Entretanto também se começou a ver “quando Deus tarda, vem no caminho” [(*Correio da Tarde*, 20-5-1860)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=090000&pesq=deus%20tarda&pasta=ano%20186).

Todas estas versões continuam frequentes ao longo do século XX. Pelo contrário, a versão pessoal, “**tardo mas não falho**”, só se encontra duas vezes na Hemeroteca, a primeira em 1960, e por comparação com Deus:

> “Eminência, eu sou como a Providência Divina: tardo mas não falho”.
> [“O Reitor, ou a ciência de sobreviver a crises”, *Jornal do Brasil*, Rio de Janeiro, 6 de outubro de 1966, caderno B, p. 5.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_08&pesq=tardo%20mas%20n%C3%A3o%20falho&pasta=ano%20196)
>
> TARDO, mas não falho. A voz do povo sempre foi a voz de Deus […]
> [“Tardo, mas não falho”, *O Fluminense*, 7 de janeiro de 1983, p. 20.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=100439_12&pesq=tardo%20mas%20n%C3%A3o&pasta=ano%20198)

“**Tardo mas não ardo**” não aparece na Hemeroteca nem no Google Books. Mesmo no Google Search geral há uma única ocorrência, ao contrário de “tardo mas não falho” que é frequente. Portanto, claramente isto começou com “Deus tarda mas não falta/falha”, que faz perfeito sentido na cultura cristã. A versão pessoal surge mais tarde. “Eu tardo mas não ardo”, como sugerido pelo Peixoto (no comentário à pergunta), poderá até ter surgido por brincadeira e por rimar. É claro que a rima teria de esperar pela primeira pessoa, porque nas outras não funciona—*tarda, arde; tardas, ardes*, etc. Poderá também ter havido influência da frase “tardo mas ardo” em [*O Pombo Enigmático* de Paulo Mendes Campos (1922-1991)](https://trapichedosoutros.blogspot.com/2009/05/o-pombo-enigmatico-de-paulo-mendes.html).

Comment: A outros links na internet (fiz pesquisa pelo bing) sobre "eu tardo, mas não ardo". Ref: https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/historia/the-dark-side-1862408/capitulo22 onde a autora menciona que a Vó usa esse ditado corriqueiramente. Gostaria de saber como fizeste a pesquisa por palavras na Hemeroteca (não tinha conhecimento deste sítio) e se sabes o significado de "ardo" na poesia de Paulo Mendes, já ajudaria muito a elucidar minha busca.

Comment: @Godofredo, curioso uns motores de busca encontrarem coisas que outros não encontram. Mas mesmo no Bing temos 1 "...ardo" contra 2179 "...falho". Há portanto pessoas que dizem  a versão com "ardo". Eu creio que é só por rimar/brincadeira: com "falho" compreende-se bem (tipicamente querendo dizer que demoram mas não falham o compromisso); enquanto com "ardo" não é tão claro. Também descobri a Hemeroteca há pouco tempo; é bestial. Eu comecei por buscar "Deus tarda" (descobri no Google que isso existia); depois "tarda mas não falta", "tarda mas não falha", "tardo mas não falho", >>

Comment: >> "tardo mas não ardo". E fui procurando década a década. É um bocado laborioso, mas recompensa. Creio que não vale a pena incluir palavras de uma ou duas letras. Ainda não apanhei as manhas todas àquilo. Tu tens o conto completo no link. Parece-me que aquilo faz parte do enigma do Pombo Enigmático, mas mais uma vez, creio que a rima foi um fator. O Pombo promete casar com a Pomba às 4h e atrasa-se. A Pomba censura-lhe o atraso, e ele diz "Tardo mas ardo"; Uma interpretação possível é que ele arde de paixão pela Pomba. A ideia da influência disto no "tardo mas não ardo" é pura especulação >>

Comment: >> minha; poderia até ser o contrário, se o autor conhecesse o "tardo mas não ardo". Em Portugal já ouvi usar informalmente "arder" no sentido 'ir por água abaixo, não se concretizar (um projeto)'. Seria uma interpretação possível para o "ardo" em "tardo mas não ardo". Tipo, prometi que vinha, fazia, etc.; demorei--então tardo mas não ardo, transferindo para mim a (ausência de) combustão do projeto/promessa.

Answer (score 0):

Conheço o " Tardo mais não ardo". A modificação desta frase para "Tardo mas não falho" deve ser uma atualização simplista que ignora a riqueza da "última flor do Lácio inculta e bela".

Comment: Carlos, bem-vindo à comunidade. Não estou a ver a relação com a "Última flor do Lácio". Não queres explicar? "Tardo mas não falho" será alteração de "tardo mas não ardo"? Ou será antes de "Deus tarda mas não falha", que já estava em uso em meados do século XIX?

Answer (score 0):

Estou surpresa: deparei-me com esse site ao digitar "tardo, mas ardo"! Esse é o "dizer" que sempre ouvi. E fui dar uma olhada para ver de qual poesia, ou texto, ele tem origem. Agora, vejo aqui, "tardo, mas não ardo"! Nunca tive notícia dessa forma.
Detalhe: é preciso pôr a vírgula na frase, né ? "Tardo, mas não ardo", ou "tardo, mas ardo".
Abraços

Answer (score -1):

Começou errado, na verdade! A expressão real é "Eu tardo, mas ardo!" e se refere à um grande amante que se atrasa para um encontro com sua amásia, porém continua cheio de paixão! Foi utilizado em uma peça teatral de representação de uma das obras de Shakespeare, se não me falha a memória.

Comment: Sabes ao menos como é a expressão no inglês?

Comment: @Jacinto Talvez venha do conto ["O pombo enigmático"](https://cronicabrasileira.org.br/cronicas/8158/o-pombo-enigmatico), de
Paulo Mendes Campos.

Comment: Embora eu concorde que "tardo mas ardo" faz mais sentido do que "tardo mas não ardo", a origem disso muito provavelmente não é Shakespeare, porque a expressão em inglês não rima... o stafusa tem razão, a expressão se encontra no conto (ou crônica) de Paulo Mendes Campos. Bem mais recente, portanto.

Comment: @stafusa, isso é um pouco o que eu já digo na minha resposta.

Comment: @Luís, eu já menciono a possível influência desse conto na minha resposta. Mas *tardo mas não ardo*, segundo o autor da pergunta, é usado como o mesmo significado que *tardo mas não falho*, e *Deus tarda mas não falta/falha* é ainda bem mais antigo que *O pombo enigmático*.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, respondi a esta resposta sem ter lido a tua - uma falha que me custou um tempo no Google. :)

Comment: @stafusa, mas o teu link tem um ano (1960; imagino que seja o ano da publicação do conto), que eu não tinha conseguido encontrar.

Comment: Pois então, o stafusa e o Jacinto têm ambos razão. "Tardo mas ardo" parece ter primeiro sido impressa seguindo a pena do Paulo Mendes Campos.